# What is the reason of Lost Connection to Device after take photos with pickedFile

Tags: flutter, camera

I want to upload to my application a few images with the camera so I do it with image_picker (version: image_picker: ^0.7.5+2) and after a few images that I upload, there is a Lost connection to device and the application is crashed. I use the same code as it is in the read me: https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker.
What can be the reason to get this error?

Comment: What is the error? Any stacktrace? Lost Connection to Device usually means something went wrong on the native side which crashed the app.

Comment: there is no any stacktrace, what does it mean native sida?

Comment: try running from XCode, try to get the crash, see if any trace is logged.